# Place N points in a 3d cube in a way that maximizes the minimum of their pairwise distances

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, computer-science, computational-geometry

Place $N$ points in a 3d cube in a way that maximizes the minimum of their pairwise distances.

The problem can easily be solved for $N\lt5$, but how to proceed for larger $N$?

Comment: Why the downvotes and the close vote?

Comment: Perhaps the downvotes are for asking a well-known hard question without any sign of research effort.

Answer (score 7):

This is equivalent to sphere packing in a cube. This type of problem is messy. Even if you look at circle packings in a square, only a few configurations have been proved optimal. The best configurations known for many other values are complicated, and it's not easy to specify a short list of possible combinatorial types of configurations to test.

Hugo Pfoertner has tabulated numerical calculations for [up to $72$ spheres in a cube](http://www.randomwalk.de/sphere/incube/index.htm). These are not guaranteed to be the best possible.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer. I suppose the packing problem is: given N, find maximal R such that N spheres of radii no less than R can be packed into a unit cube. In addition, find the corresponding packing configuration(s). The equivalent maximized minimal pairwise distance of my original question is then R(1+2R)

Comment: 1. The packing problem as formulated above is different from the standard formulation, in which the quantity to be maximized is the volume of the spheres. Is it obvious that the two are equivalent?                                                 2. Correction to the above: 2R(1+2R)

Answer (score 3):

A very simple, cute "math-folklore" solution for $N=9$ goes as folows: the eight vertices and the center of the unit cube form a configuration of nine points, in which the minimum distance between them is $\sqrt3/2$. This is the maximum of the minimum over all configurations. Proof: partition the cube into eight cubes of edge length $1/2$. No matter how you place nine points in the unit cube, two of them must be contained in one of the small cubes; the distance between them is at most $\sqrt3/2$. With a bit more elaboration one can prove that the extreme configuration is unique. Analogous proofs work for five points in a square and seventeen points in the $4$-dim. cube, but fails in dimensions higher than $4$.

Comment: Thank  you, this is very elegant. As a practical matter, I will rarely need to go beyond N=9.

Comment: The proofs for $N\le 4$ and $N=8$ are not very hard either. The proofs and configurations for $N=7, 9, 10,$ and $11$ (very non-trivial) were found by Jonathan Shaer, and for $N=14$ by Antal Joos, this last one one quite recently, despite an long-known and highly believable conjecture. As far as I know, no proof exists for any $N>14$.